# Cannot run tests using NUnit Test Runner from SpecFlow feature files

Tags: nunit, resharper, specflow, resharper-9.1

Using the current version of ReSharper (9.1) and NUnit (2.6.4), whenever I right click a feature or step in a feature file and click ReSharper's "Run Unit Tests" it throws an error and says no unit tests found.

I've found if I use the built in MSTest or if use SpecRunner, it works fine, but I lose the features of NUnit.

I can run NUnit tests fine normally, and confirmed that the proper version of NUnit is listed in my SpecFlow config, and ReSharper settings, and everything appears to line up.

Comment: Do you see the same behaviour from VS Test Explorer ?  (You need the NUnit VS Adapter though from https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ab922d0-21c0-4f06-ab5f-4ecd1fe7175d

Comment: yes, the exact same behavior

Comment: Can you upload a small repro?  like to a github repo

Comment: which version of Specflow?

Comment: related to [this](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/435)? maybe updating to the latest version will solve the problem?